# Write text on a bitmap image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image

Well, I try to write on an image in C#, my code is:

```
public string WriteOnImage(Bitmap Image, string NameImage, string TextFileName)

    {
        string Message = "OK";
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(Image);

            using (Graphics graphImage = Graphics.FromImage(Image))

            {

                graphImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                string line;

                // Read the file and display it line by line.
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(Resources.C_PATH_DESTINO_IMG + TextFileName);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    graphImage.DrawString(line, new Font("Courier New", 15, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(0, 0));
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                    bitMapImage.Save(Resources.C_PATH_DESTINO_IMG + NameImage, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    graphImage.Dispose();
                    bitMapImage.Dispose();
                }

                file.Close();
            }
            return Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogWrite("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return Message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

this method doesn't work because doesn't write on the image, please help me.

PD: I'm sorry for my english but I'm Latino jeje, thanks.

Comment: Im not sure about this, but try to change coordinates `new Point(0, 0)`. Maybe text is written above or below image?

Comment: I notice the following line in your code: `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";` Are you trying to return the image to a browser client?

Comment: Provide more information. What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you receive an error or not? What kind of behavior do you observe?

Comment: Kamil I try with different coordinates but i have the same result...

Comment: Just an FYI, since you have a `using` statement, `graphImage.Dispose();` and `bitMapImage.Dispose();` don't **need** to be called.

Comment: Black Frog, i try to do this in a Web Services, the WS search an image, after that i have to write on, then return the image in an array

Comment: mostruash, when i said doesn't work i mean the image saved is like the original image, no changes.

Comment: @meko_bgs, what happens if you just use 'Message' instead of reading from the text file? Is the text written then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are drawing on the wrong bitmap

```
 Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(Image);
 using (Graphics graphImage = Graphics.FromImage(Image))
```

should be

```
 Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(Image);
 using (Graphics graphImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage))
```