# How could you save the full text from a Textbox(with scroll bars) in winforms as an image?

Tags: c#, save

I was searching for a solution to save a text as an image and I found this page:
[How could you save the text from a Textbox or Label in winforms as an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973217/how-could-you-save-the-text-from-a-textbox-or-label-in-winforms-as-an-image)
The best answer of the above question, only saves a rectangle with equal size to the Textbox control (full appearance of the textbox: border, background color, etc.).
It is good But it does not save all the text from a Textbox with scroll bars!
What is the solution?

Comment: First make the textbox (temporarily) larger so that the scrollbars disappear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
int iPos = 10;
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(200,(lines.Length * 12) + 20);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    g.DrawString(line, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, new PointF(5, iPos));
    iPos += 12;
}
```

Now you can show the image or save the image in your drive or database

```
PictureBox1.Image = myBitmap
```

Comment: Thanks Shell. I modified font-name and size and I must say it really works.